# Jquery multiply value only if next input is greater than 1

Tags: jquery, forms, if-statement, input, numbers

Hopefully this will be a fairly easy question. I'm still learning jquery, so please bear with me and thank you for your patience. I couldn't find the answer by searching.
I'm coding a fairly simple site, and it needed a form, which handles a huge amount of rather repetitive data, so targeting by individual IDs is too cumbersome.

What I'm trying to get it to do is multiply the value of each checkbox (when the checkbox is checked) by the next input -only-, and add that to the total price displayed in an input field at the end of the form.

I got it to multiply, but it had the problem that if the input fields were empty or had a value of 0, 
however, if I set the values of each input to 1 minimum, it sends all the values of those to the server as well, causing an extremely cluttered form intake. (I need it to be readable on receipt, after all...)

So i thought, to breakproof the input boxes, I'll code it so that
- if the value of the input is greater than 1, it'll multiply the number of the input by the number of the checkbox and add that number to the total
- if not, it simply adds the value of the checkbox to the total rather than multiplying anything. That way even if they mess with the input to make it -1 or something the sum still holds properly.

I tried to do that and it broke, and I can't seem to get it working...
Any help would be appreciated, any explanation of how to get there also would be appreciated.

This is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var price = 0;
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      if ((this).next('input').val() > 1) {
        price += $(this).val() * $(this).next("input[name^='qty']").val();
      } else {
        price += parseInt($(this).val());
      }
    });
    $("#price").val(price);
  });
  $('input[type="number"]').change(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').trigger('change');
  });
});
```

This is a sampling of the relevant html, the each checkbox and input pair is together in its own div like this:

```
 <div class="lineitem"><input type="checkbox" name="SN56803" value="96" /> <input type="number" name="qtySN56803" class="qty" min="-1" max="100"> </div>
```

Comment: What problem does it have if the quantity is 0? Shouldn't that just multiply the price by 0, and add nothing to the total?

Comment: `$('input:checkbox').trigger('change');` is going to trigger lots of events. You should probably use `input:checkbox:first`

Comment: Or move all that code into a named function, which you call from both event handlers.

Comment: I would have to see some of the form as well. Form what I am understanding. There are both checkbox and text input fields in the form and once someone checks the checkbox the value of the checkbox is multiplied by the value in the text input and then added to a text input at the bottom of the form. Is that correct? Again seeing some of the HTML would help.

Comment: do you need to multiply all of the checkboxes and show the result in the bottom box?

Comment: Sorry! To clarify, i need to multiply -each- checkbox only by its respective input, add the results together, and show that number in the bottom box, which has an id of #price.

Comment: That is correct, I'm sorry the form is very long to paste here, but it's all structured like what is shown. there's a second div after each checkbox-input pair div that's just the description then the price is at the end along with a submit button. fairly basic stuff there. the problem with multiplying by 0 is I want the price to increment when each checkbox is clicked, even before the input box changes, because if checked i want it to assume the quantity is 1. I found a workaround that set the next input to 1 at minimum whenever its checkbox is checked but i dont know if that's ideal

Answer (score 0):

This code works. Sorry it took a while to get back to you. Let me know if you have any additional questions.

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
        <div class="lineitem"><input type="checkbox" name="SN56803" value="96" /> <input type="number" name="qtySN56803" class="qty" min="0" max="100"> </div>
        <div class="lineitem"><input type="checkbox" name="SN56803" value="22" /> <input type="number" name="qtySN56803" class="qty" min="0" max="100"> </div>
        <div class="lineitem"><input type="checkbox" name="SN56803" value="2" /> <input type="number" name="qtySN56803" class="qty" min="0" max="100"> </div>
        <div class="lineitem"><input type="checkbox" name="SN56803" value="66" /> <input type="number" name="qtySN56803" class="qty" min="0" max="100"> </div>
        <div class="lineitem"><input type="checkbox" name="SN56803" value="45" /> <input type="number" name="qtySN56803" class="qty" min="0" max="100"> </div>
        <div class="lineitem"><input type="checkbox" name="SN56803" value="23" /> <input type="number" name="qtySN56803" class="qty" min="0" max="100"> </div>
        <div class="lineitem"><input type="checkbox" name="SN56803" value="87" /> <input type="number" name="qtySN56803" class="qty" min="0" max="100"> </div>
        <div class="lineitem"><input type="checkbox" name="SN56803" value="68" /> <input type="number" name="qtySN56803" class="qty" min="0" max="100"> </div>
        <div class="lineitem"><input type="checkbox" name="SN56803" value="5" /> <input type="number" name="qtySN56803" class="qty" min="0" max="100"> </div>
        <label for="">Button Total</label>
        <input type="number" id="btnTotal" disabled>
        <label for="">Greand Total</label>
        <input type="number" id="grandTotal" disabled>
    </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

            var totalSum = [], //store the numbers that will be added together 
                grandSum = 0; // store the grand total

            // Function to be used in the array redue to add the input numbers together
            function sumTotal(val, val2) {
                grandSum = val + val2; // add the numbers from the "totalSum" array
                return val + val2; // return the result from the array reduce method
            }

            // listen to the checkbox change state
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
                var inputResult = $(this).val() * $(this).next('input').val(); //multiply the value of the checkbox and the number input

                totalSum.push(inputResult); // push the current input sum into the array to be summed 
                totalSum.reduce(sumTotal);  // sum the numbers in the "totalSum" array using the array reduce method

                $('#btnTotal').val(inputResult);                // show the sum of the two input fields
                $('#grandTotal').val(grandSum || inputResult);  // show the sum of grand total of the numbers 
            });    
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If each checkbox and input box is under the corresponding div and you only need to multiply it at a time, you can try this, you don’t need to `each` every time, Maybe it helps you.

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
                var price = 0;
                var _next = $(this).next();
                if (_next.val() > 1) {
                    price += $(this).val() * _next.val();
                }
                else {
                    price += parseInt($(this).val());
                }
                $("#price").val(price);

            });
            $('input[type="number"]').change(function() {
                $(this).prev().trigger('change');
            });
```

```html
<div class="lineitem"><input type="checkbox" name="SN56803" value="96" /> <input type="number" name="qtySN56803" class="qty" min="-1" max="100"> </div>
```